# Aggregate nested field with condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I've **multiple** documents in following format:

Document **#1**:

```
{
   "stats":{
      "cars":[
         {
            "isEnabled": false,
            "name":"BMW"
         },
         {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "name":"Mercedes"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Document **#2**:

```
{
   "stats":{
      "cars":[
         {
            "isEnabled": true,  <--- changed to TRUE
            "name":"BMW"
         },
         {
            "isEnabled": false, <--- changed to FALSE
            "name":"Mercedes"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And I'm trying to achieve result which will give me overview of `cars` which has `isEnabled` set on `true` in **ALL** documents.

The aggregation result should look like this (simplified):

```
{
   "buckets": [
      {
          "key": "BMW",
          "doc_count": 1   <---- Only 1, because 1 document has set true in "isEnabled"
      },      
      {
          "key": "Mercedes",
          "doc_count": 1   <---- Only 1, because 1 document has set true in "isEnabled"
      },
   ]
}
```

---

#### What I've tried

I've tried multiple aggregations, but I'm not able to get the results based on the `isEnabled` condition, example what I've tried:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "carResult": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "stats.cars.name.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "carsResult": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "stats.cars.isEnabled"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make stats.cars nested you can use following query to aggregate enabled cars.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "carResult": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "stats.cars"
      },
      "inner": {
        "asd": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "stats.cars.isEnabled": true
            }
          },
          "inner": {
            "asd": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "stats.cars.name.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you make a field mapping nested from the documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html